# Validation of the browser in dropdown form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, dropdown

I have implemented a dropdown for the login but when I submit it with some empty field the dropdown is closed and therefore the validation notifications of the browser don't appear.

This is my dropdown with the form:

```
<div class="btn-group dropleft" >
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <spring:message code="master.page.login"/>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu p-4" style="width: 250px;" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <form:form action="j_spring_security_check" modelAttribute="credentials">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                <form:input id="username" path="username" cssClass="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required="required" />    
                <form:errors class="error" path="username" />
            </div>                                  
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">
                    <img src="images/password.png" style="height:15px;width:auto" />
                </span>
                <form:password id="password" path="password" cssClass="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required="required"/>  
                <form:errors class="error" path="password" />
            </div>                                  
          </div>          
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Login</button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <jstl:if test="${showError == true}">
            <div class="alert alert-danger small" role="alert">
                 ERROR!
            </div>
          </jstl:if>

        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried adding an 'onclick' event for the submit to try to open the dropdown with jQuery but it doesn't seem that the button works as it should. I have used this code that, by contrast, has helped me to open the dropdown when there is an error of incorrect credentials when calling the database:

```
$(".dropleft").addClass("show");
$("#dropdownMenu").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
$(".p-4").addClass("show");
```

Any idea how to get to visualize the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is any click inside the dropdown closes it and it can be solved, in this particular case, with:

```
$("[modelAttribute='credentials']").click(e => { e.stopPropagation() })
```

For the record, placing a `<form>` inside a dropdown is a **no:no**.

Comment: That was the thing, but getting the 'dropdown-menu' instead the form, thanks. And could you explain why placing a 'form' inside a dropdown is a no:no?

Comment: @atila665 Each of them can be safely considered one of the most complex UI elements, considering they need to be handled differently on different devices (think about how differently mobiles treat input fields, having to render a keyboard on half the screen, add to that differences between how browsers handle events, differences between device types (pointer vs touch) and add responsiveness and validation issues). Mixing two elements of this complexity together will make your code a lot harder to maintain, in the happy and unlikely case it works  flawlessly on any device.

Comment: I had never thought about it in that way, I'll take it into account from now on, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Improving the answer of [Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502693/validation-of-the-browser-in-dropdown-form/51502940#51502940), for my case worked I've needed to add this code:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This will make all dropdowns in all your pages not close when clicked. That's why I used a selector specific to your particular case. Most people want their dds to close once they clicked a menu option.